# How to make a step-chart in Microsoft Access?

Tags: ms-access, plot

Currently, I have a table with the dates of price changes in various goods. I have a form with a line chart like:

[image]

Instead, it would be more accurate for me to have a step-chart like:

[image]

But I can't find how to change the chart type to a step-chart in Access 2007. Any ideas?

Comment: Step Charts are not a standard type. Creating them in Excel is outlined here at [Peltiertech](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/ChartsHowTo/StepChart.html). I suspect it can be adapted for Access.

Answer (score 2):

One way you could "fake" such a chart would be to create a query that repeats the previous price immediately before the next one. For example, for the sample data

```
Date        Price
----------  -----
2013-08-01  $6.00
2013-08-02  $5.00
2013-08-03  $5.00
2013-08-04  $6.00
2013-08-05  $8.00
2013-08-06  $9.00
2013-08-07  $7.00
2013-08-08  $6.00
2013-08-09  $7.00
```

you could use the query

```
SELECT [Date], [Price] FROM Prices
UNION ALL
SELECT DateAdd("s",86399,[Date]), [Price] FROM Prices
ORDER BY 1;
```

to produce the data

```
Date                Price
------------------- -----
2013-08-01          $6.00
2013-08-01 23:59:59 $6.00
2013-08-02          $5.00
2013-08-02 23:59:59 $5.00
2013-08-03          $5.00
2013-08-03 23:59:59 $5.00
2013-08-04          $6.00
2013-08-04 23:59:59 $6.00
2013-08-05          $8.00
2013-08-05 23:59:59 $8.00
2013-08-06          $9.00
2013-08-06 23:59:59 $9.00
2013-08-07          $7.00
2013-08-07 23:59:59 $7.00
2013-08-08          $6.00
2013-08-08 23:59:59 $6.00
2013-08-09          $7.00
2013-08-09 23:59:59 $7.00
```

and then if you display that data as an X-Y chart you would get something like this:

[image: PriceChart.png]